# XlsxWriter formatting in nested loop

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have tried all imaginable combos from https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html and any Stack Overflow answer I could find that's related.

99.99% chance it's something simple, as these are normally the reason I hit a dead end.

I'm writing a summary to the first sheet and looping through a dict of df's to write a number of df's to separate sheets (this works fine)

I can applied number formats to the summary but not in the loop.

```
writer = ExcelWriter('Players ' + str(date.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H;%M;%S")) +'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
summary.to_excel(writer,'Summary',index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Summary']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.000'})
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 15)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 15)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 6, format1)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 15)
worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C100', {'type': '3_color_scale',
                                         'min_color': "green",
                                         'mid_color': "yellow",
                                         'max_color': "red"})
#Above works
#below doesn't format

#loop through summary and players individual tables
#write an individual table to excel if score > 0
for index, row in summary.iterrows():
    for tbl in player_df_dict:
        if (row['Player_1'] == tbl[0]) & (row['Player_2'] == tbl[1]) & (row['Score']>0):
            player_df_dict[tbl].to_excel(writer,str(tbl[0])+" and "+str(tbl[1]),index=False, columns=cols)
            worksheet = writer.sheets[str(tbl[0])+" and "+str(tbl[1])]
            #format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.000'})
            #worksheet.set_column('D:D', 20, format1)
            #worksheet.set_column('D:D', 20, format2)

writer.save()
```

I've tried:

- using the original workbook object (from the summary code)
- instantiating a new workbook object in all variations of inside and
  outside each loop
- same for both above with sheet object
- same for both above with setting and applying format

Comment: Can you be clearer on actual vs desired output? Doesn't work mean nothing gets written, or it gets written but not formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't exactly present a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

All I can tell you is that setting the column works; I am also doing it in two slightly different ways (yours + using `writer.sheets[tabname]` ,ie without creating an explicit variable for the worksheet.

In my example below, the formatting gets applied in both cases.

Also, define the formatting outside of the loop - it's an attribute of the book, not of the sheet.

The code below creates a dataframe of random floats, exports it to excel and formats columns B and C - remember that Python's column 0 is column A)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

writer =pd.ExcelWriter('xlsx_test.xlsx')
format_1 = writer.book.add_format({'num_format': '0.000'})
for i in range(3):
    tabname = str(i)
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4) ).to_excel(writer, tabname)
    writer.sheets[tabname].set_column(1,2, None, format_1)

for i in ["a","b"]:
    tabname = i
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4) ).to_excel(writer, tabname)
    ws = writer.sheets[i]
    ws.set_column(1,2, None, format_1)

writer.close()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about the mcve but this it's from a work code base (changed df  names etc), the df's are filled with sensitive data and it would take me days to recreate.

Your code works fine running as a standalone. Once I try use it in my app (the nested loop) I get the same issue. It will resize the columns i.e. replacing None with 16 but num_format is not applied

Comment: No one wants to see your data. We just need a mcve to understand what's wrong. Without it, I'm not sure how we can help you. When you say the format is not applied, how many decimal digits are shown? Have you tried defining the format outside the loop, like I did?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another bit of code that also changes the formatting? There is a precedence whereby row settings override column settings or viceversa. I can't remember exactly but it should be easy to look up.

Comment: I get you yeah, wrote some code to try replicate the issue and your solution works!
Must be something like you say, can't see it though. Are we talking XlsxWriter code or any code? Appreciate the help by the way

Comment: Fixed! "99.99% chance it's something simple".. and indeed it was. The dtype of some of the columns in the source df was wrong. Feeling fairly stupid now haha